# Up arrow in gnome terminal to review command line history ignores commands with leading whitespace. Is there a workaround?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

When writing python code (using gvim) I often keep complex command line commands for test cases saved in my docstrings. A common time-wasting error I make is copying the entire line from the python file and pasting it into the terminal.

For an example one of my functions looks like this

```
@profile
def incremental_test(ibs, qaid_list, daid_list=None):
    """
    Plots the scores/ranks of correct matches while varying the size of the
    database.

    Args:
        ibs       (list) : IBEISController object
        qaid_list (list) : list of annotation-ids to query

    CommandLine:
        python dev.py -t inc --db PZ_MTEST --qaid 1:30:3 --cmd

        python dev.py --db PZ_MTEST --allgt --cmd

        python dev.py --db PZ_MTEST --allgt -t inc

        python dev.py -t inc --db PZ_MTEST --qaid 1:30:3 --cmd

        python dev.py -t inc --db PZ_Master0
        python dev.py -t inc --db GZ_ALL --ninit 100 --noqcache

    Example:
        >>> from ibeis.all_imports import *  # NOQA
        >>> ibs = ibeis.opendb('PZ_MTEST')
        >>> qaid_list = ibs.get_valid_aids()
        >>> daid_list = None
    """
    from ibeis.model.hots import automated_matcher
    ibs1 = ibs
    num_initial = ut.get_argval('--ninit', type_=int, default=0)
    return automated_matcher.incremental_test(ibs1, num_initial)
```

And I want to copy one of the various commands into the terminal to test it.

Initially when I copy and paste one of these lines works fine, but if I change code and want to run the test again I find myself pressing the up arrow to get to the previous command in my history. But because the command had leading whitespace I get some other command. What makes this worse is that often the previous command is very similar; maybe I had added a --verbose flag or something, so I don't always catch it right away.

Currently my workaround is that I have to be careful to copy the command from the start of the first non whitespace character or I have to repaste the command. Both of these options break my coding rhythm and I often find myself wanting for a better solution.

With this modivating example my question is:

Is there is a way to configure the gnome-terminal such that when you press up-arrow it gives you the last command even if it has leading whitespace.

I guess an alternative workaround would be for ctrl+shift+c in vim to copy the line to the clipboard but lstrip the whitespace, but I would prefer a terminal hack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's caused by the `ignorespace` value in `$HISTCONTROL`. From `man bash`:

> HISTCONTROL
>
> A  colon-separated  list  of values controlling how commands are
>   saved on the history list.   If  the  list  of  values  includes
>   ignorespace,  lines  which  begin with a space character are not
>   saved in the history list.

It could be caused by the `HISTIGNORE` variable, though that usually contains commands to skip.

Just reconfigure your shell history in `~/.bashrc` by setting different defaults, e.g.

```
HISTIGNORE=ignoredups
```

Comment: Or possibly `HISTIGNORE`?

Comment: @DanielBeck: Thanks, I was just editing that in :-) Less likely though, right?